# Fetchall() on sqllite db returning unicode strings [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, unicode

I am running into some issues running fetchall().

I have a table defined like this:

```
with bookDB:
    bookCur = bookDB.cursor()
    bookCur.execute("CREATE TABLE Books(bookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT, Author TEXT, Genre TEXT)")
    bookCur.close()
```

Now if I want to search the database for books by genre, I have this code:

```
with bookDB:
        bookCur = bookDB.cursor()
        bookCur.execute("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Genre=?",(query,)) 
        booklist=bookCur.fetchall()
        book = ''.join(str(i) for i in booklist)
        bookCur.close()
        return book;
```

I would like to join all the items in the book list to make one string that is assigned to book but when I do this, all the TEXT fields arein the unicode format (u'TEXTHERE') and the front and end parentheses also stay. I know I can use split multiple times or delmitters, but there must be something I am doing wrong. How do I stop this from happening? Any tips?

Here is what I get back from fetchall:

```
[(133, u'Jurassic Park', u'Crichton', u'Sci-Fi')]
```

I would like a string like this

```
133>>Jurassic Park>>Crichton>>Sci-Fi
```

To send back through a socket.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: You will have several books in the list, do you want to concatenate them all or return a list already formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`booklist` is a list of `tuple`s representing the query columns in the database. By doing `book = ''.join(str(i) for i in booklist)` you're just concatenating the string representation of the `tuples` in `booklist`.

Try something like this:

```
book = '|'.join(['>>'.join(map(str, row)) for row in booklist])
```

This will return something like this:

```
"133>>Jurassic Park>>Crichton>>Sci-Fi|134>>Star Wars>>Crichton>>Sci-Fi"
```

where `>>` is the columns separator and `|` is the row separators. If you need other representation for the separators just change the string literals.

In that code, the inner `join` will concatenate the `tuples` (columns) and the outer will concatenate the `rows`. [`map(str, row)`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#map) is a trick to convert the tuple into a list of `string` objects applying `str` method to every element in the tuple. It is needed because simply doing `join` on an iterable that contains non string elements returns a `TypeError` exception.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks friend, it did work. May I ask you what the significance of map()? What is it doing?

Comment: @cjuf I'm glad, I'll update the answer to explain `map`'s usage.